# How to create a Mumbai Faucet

Tags: solidity, evm, nodes, polygon, faucets

I want to create a Mumbai faucet to deliver Matic to people.
To be able to do that I guess I need to set up a mining node so I can get Matic for validating transactions and them give this coins to people.

Although I didn’t find any content on how to setup a Mumbai node. How do I do this?

Also, I'm thinking this right?

Answer (score 0):

for creating a faucet there are 2 ways first is you can create a contract and funds with matic tokens. and in the contract you can create a claimMatic function to claim the matic tokens. you can also implement the waiting period of 24 hours for a user who already claimed.

and second way you have to setup your own node.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered you can't set up a node to polygon mumbai since it ins't a public blockchain. But you can ask for faucet on this form:

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe4npoGldJknEs9EBtPaV3AS-0HTso2IuMWDCiMmLEMCx8euQ/viewform

Comment: Where did you find this link? Belongs to whom?